# IR receiver transmitter High frequency

Tags: ir

I build photo gate, to detect throwing ball. 
It works fine when delay time in main loop for max 40 milliseconds. 
Problems start when I delay every loop only for 20 milliseconds, now my LED which indicates if something broke path between IR led and IR receiver, **blinks occasionally**, if I set delay for 10 milliseconds and turn on, then LED is off for 2 seconds, then start blinking very fast and is ON for rest time, until I break IR path. I think some physics is going on here which I don't understand.

I also would like to ask if it is possible to **narrow IR wave path to be more like laser** (going strait into one direction) and how I can **control sensitivity** of IR detection

This is schematic [image]

[IR transmiter](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81010/tsal6200.pdf)
[IR reciever](http://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/file/view/IR-Receiver-AX-1838HS.pdf)

Code:

```
//define pins. I used pins 4 and 5
#define irLedPin 4          // IR Led on this pin
#define irSensorPin 5       // IR sensor on this pin
#define buzzerPin 2       // buzzer on this pin

int irRead(int readPin, int triggerPin); //function prototype

void setup()
{
  pinMode(irSensorPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(irLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600); 
  // prints title with ending line break 
  Serial.println("Program Starting"); 
  // wait for the long string to be sent 
  delay(100); 
}

void loop()
{  

  bool isOn = irRead(irSensorPin, irLedPin);
  //Serial.println(isOn); //display the results
  if(isOn == true)
  {
    digitalWrite(buzzerPin, HIGH);
  }
  else
  {
     digitalWrite(buzzerPin, LOW);
  }
  delay(10); 
}


int irRead(int readPin, int triggerPin)
{
  int halfPeriod = 13; //one period at 38.5khZ is aproximately 26 microseconds
  int cycles = 23; //26 microseconds * 23 is more or less 600 us
  int i;
  for (i=0; i <=cycles; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH); 
    delayMicroseconds(halfPeriod);
    digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW); 
    delayMicroseconds(halfPeriod - 1);     // - 1 to make up for digitaWrite overhead    
  }
  return digitalRead(readPin);
}
```

Comment: You can get IR laser diodes if you want a beam.

Comment: Or you can use red laser beam and use that as a IR source.

Comment: @Avamander, wow that's strange, I just checked and it works, but how? my red laser has 570 nm and IR reciver 950nm and it works, how ?

Comment: The laser has close enough wavelength, the same thing works with red LEDs too.

Answer (score 3):

While you are doing a `delay()` you can't be doing anything else - that includes looking to see if the beam has been broken by the ball.

You *must not* use `delay()` in your sketch, instead use `millis()` as in the **BlinkWithoutDelay** example sketch in the IDE's *File -> Examples* menu.

Also how you are dealing with your IR system is incorrect.  You are first generating a brief square wave and then afterwards you are looking to see what was received.  Instead you need to be generating the square wave and *at the same time* see if that square wave is being received.  Normally that is achieved by using one of the PWM outputs of the Arduino set to the right frequency to generate a constant waveform which the receiver then senses all the time.